# If $I$ an interval and $x_1,x_2,x_3\in I$, why $t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3\in I$ when $t_1+t_2+t_3=1, t_i\in [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $I$ an interval and $x_1,x_2,x_3\in I$. Why $t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3\in I$ when $t_1+t_2+t_3=1, t_i\in [0,1]$ ?

Attempts : $t_3=1-t_1-t_2$ and thus $$t_1x_2+t_2x_2+t_3x_3=\underbrace{t_1x_1+(1-t_1)x_3}_{\in I}+t_2(x_2+x_3).$$
Now, $t_1x_1+(1-t_1)x_3\in I$, but this don't prove that $t_1x_1+(1-t_1)x_3+t_2(x_2+x_3)\in I$. Any idea ?

Comment: Assume $a<x_i<b$ for each $i$ and verify that $a<\sum x_it_i<b$ . Similar argument works if $I$ is not open but closed or half-closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WLOG, suppose $x_1 \leqslant  x_2\leqslant x_3$, then 
$$
x_1 =(t_1+t_2+t_3)x_1\leqslant t_1 x_1 + t_2 x_2 + t_3 x_3 \leqslant (t_1 + t_2 + t_3)x_3 = x_3. 
$$
Since $[x_1, x_3]\subset I$, so is $t_1 x_1 + t_2 x_2 + t_3x_3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3=(t_1+t_2)\left(\frac{t_1}{t_1+t_2}x_1+\frac{t_2}{t_1+t_2}x_2\right)+t_3x_3$$

Comment: But the problem is still the same : why $\frac{t_1}{t_1+t_2}x_1+\frac{t_2}{t_1+t_2}x_2\in I$ ?

Comment: The two fractions add to 1.